# changin a word format in UITextView from keyboard input when the word begins with @

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

im triyin to format a word from keyboard input in a uitextfield,

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {


    let words = textView.text.components(separatedBy: " ")
    for word in words{
        if word.hasPrefix("@"){
            let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSFontAttributeName: self.textView.font!] as [String : Any]
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: word, attributes: attributes)
            self.textView.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: range.location)
            let cursor =  NSRange(location: self.textView.selectedRange.location+1, length: 0) //textView.text.range(of: word)
            textView.selectedRange = cursor
            return true
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

[image]

any ideas how to ge it done
the expected result should be *@yoel l*

Comment: It looks like it's working for you - please describe the exact problem you are having?

Comment: the desired reult should be @yoel in blue and the rest should be in black

Comment: To be clear - you have typed "@yoel" in the textfield and above is what you get back?

Comment: i typed this is a string @yoel l but what i  see is this is @@y@o@e@l@y@y every key input repeat @ with pressed key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check the last word after every space for a word that has '@' in it:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
     if text == " ",let lastWord = textView.text.components(separatedBy: " ").last, lastWord.contains("@"), let lastWordRange = (textView.text as? NSString)?.range(of: lastWord){
         let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSFontAttributeName: self.textView.font!] as [String : Any]
         let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lastWord, attributes: attributes)
         textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in:lastWordRange, with:attributedString)
     }
     return true
}
```